# Magento2 Multiple Category Layouts

Tags: php, magento, magento2

How do you have a completely different look for each category in magento 2 (custom category layouts), in magento 1.* I know you could change the template either checking for the page layout or changing the template in the custom layout update via xml however magento 2 doesn't let you change templates in here?

I tried following http://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-design-a-custom-magento-2-category-page-template/ but didn't really understand how it worked.

Magento 2 seems much more difficult to get my head around than the previous version so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a xml file `catalog_category_view_id_{{id}}.xml` under your theme > Magento_Catalog > layout and change list file.

For detail :
http://sumankc.com/2016/12/10/different-template-for-different-categories-in-magento-2-category_id-layout-handle-in-m2/

Comment: good tip to complete the idea add the following to the xml file:  <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
<action method="setTemplate">
<argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/list-new.phtml</argument>
</action>
</referenceBlock>

Answer (score 0):

GO To admin -> Manage Category and select particular category that you want different design and ther is one tab "custom design" . in this tab there is one drop down list with name "custom design". you can select custom design for perticular category.

Comment: This only gives me the option to chose a theme thought, I've already created a custom theme just want to add another category view which looks completely different to the standard. Surely I don't have to create another theme to add an extra category layout?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps that you will follow in this Magento 2: Change category page layout

- On the Admin page, look for Product section. Then click on Categories section under Inventory.
- You can see the category tree on the left, choose any category for which you want to change the page layout.
- Then find the Custom design section, click on it.
- Now you can change both category page layout and custom theme here.
- In this section, you can use 2 fields to change the category page layout. The Page Layout and Custom Layout Update.
- Page Layout field gives you 6 options to change the category layout.
- The Custom Layout Update allows you to update the theme layout with XML code.
- These are the options for changing category page layout.